# C# - split a RichTextBox line in two based on the caret position

Tags: c#, winforms, richtextbox

I've got a RichTextBox, here referred to as `box`.

```
string currentline = box.Lines[box.GetLineFromCharIndex(box.SelectionStart)];
```

That line there fetches the line the caret is in. It works excellently.

However, I have a need to get two strings from this. The first is everything on that line UP to the caret, and the second is everything on that line AFTER it.

For instance, if the line is `How is you|r day going?`, with `|` representing the caret, I would get `How is you` and `r day going?`, separately.

I wrote this monstrosity, which works:

```
string allbefore = box.Text.Substring(0, box.SelectionStart);
string allafter = box.Text.Substring(box.SelectionStart, box.Text.Length - box.SelectionStart);
string linebefore = "";
for (int i = 0; i < allbefore.Length; i++)
{
    linebefore += allbefore[i];
    if (allbefore[i] == '\n')
        linebefore = "";
}
string lineafter = "";
for (int i = 0; i < allafter.Length; i++)
{
    if (allafter[i] == '\n')
        break;
    else
        lineafter += allafter[i];
}
```

It gives me the result I want, but involves looping through EVERY character in the entire box, which just hurts. Is there an easy way to do this I'm just missing? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
string currentline = box.Lines[box.GetLineFromCharIndex(box.SelectionStart)];
var listOfStrings = new List<string>();
string[] splitedBox = currentline.Split('|');
foreach(string sp in splitedBox)
{
    string[] lineleft = sp.Split('\n');
    listOfStrings.Add(lineleft[lineleft.Count() - 1]);
}
```

In the first approach we are splitting the line by char `|` than finding if we have any `\n` if it exsist we are taking the values accordingly

Another approach could be

```
string box = "How is \n you|r day \n going?";
bool alllinesremoved = true;
while(alllinesremoved)
{
    if(box.Contains('\n'))
    {
        if(box.IndexOf('\n') > box.IndexOf('|'))
        {
            box = box.Remove(box.IndexOf('\n'), (box.Length - box.IndexOf('\n')));
        }
        else
        {
            box = box.Remove(0, box.IndexOf('\n') + 1);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        alllinesremoved = false;
    }
}
string[] splitedBox = box.Split('|');
```

in the second approach we are removing the characters before and after the `\n` and then splitting the string. I think the second one seems more good to me.

Comment: Excellent! With a couple tweaks, your method worked quite well. Thank you very much!

Comment: Pleasure is all mine @Trystan. Happy Coding. :)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using line.split? Not sure if this is what you want.

Comment: I guess theoretically I could insert some obscure unicode character like ∡ at the caret, then split it based on that. Not a bad idea, actually, I'll definitely do that if I can't find anything more official ;)

Answer (score 0):

Store the position of `\n` using `indexOf` and, if >= 0, that is, the string contains it, use `substring` and assign the value otherwise.

```
string allbefore = box.Text.Substring(0, box.SelectionStart);
string allafter = box.Text.Substring(box.SelectionStart, box.Text.Length - box.SelectionStart);
int newLinePos = allBefore.lastIndexOf("\n");
string lineBefore = ((newLinePos >= 0) ? (allBefore.substring(newLinePos + 1)) : (allBefore));
    newLinePos = allafter.indexOf("\n");
string lineAfter = ((newLinePost >= 0) ? (allAfter.substring(0, newLinePos)) : (allAfter));
```